# How to call the overloaded aligned new and delete operators in `C++17`?

Tags: c++, alignment, overloading, new-operator, delete-operator

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) we can see several new overloads of `new` and `delete`, as well as `new[]` and `delete[]` were added. I can't find any examples of usage with the new aligned overloads, neither on cppreference nor anywhere else. I've experimented with them for quite some time now and I can't find out how to trigger these aligned dynamically allocated calls. Anyone has any idea, kindly share an example.

Comment: Show us your experiments. What is wrong with them? Since C++17, _new expression_ should handle over-aligned types automatically by using a special version of `operator new`.

Comment: It important to ensure your compiler has support for this feature: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support

Comment: @AntonyPeacock Note that the corresponding row is called _"Dynamic memory allocation for over-aligned data (P0035R4)"_.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to specify the align as keyword on your type and then just call new and delete as normal.  I have put together an article with examples about it here: https://github.com/Twon/Alignment/blob/master/docs/alignment_in_C%2B%2B.md.  An example is:

```
#include <memory>

int main() {
    class alignas(16) float4 {
        float f[4];
    }; 

    std::unique_ptr<float4 > aligned_vec4(std::make_unique<float4 >());
}
```

And an example with the Intel compiler which currently make this feature available via the aligned_new extension header: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/aligned-operator-new-support-in-intel-c-compiler

Comment: `aligned_new` is not a header file from the C++ Standard. In C++17, _new expression_ will use a special version of `operator new` for over-aligned types automatically. AFAIK, until C++17, there is no portable way how to dynamically allocate memory for over-aligned objects. Usually, `posix_memalign` or similar platform-specific functions were used.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  The aligned_new header was an extension proposed in http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0035r4.html.  The Intel Compiler supports aligned_new from version 15 on wards.  However while this proposal was accepted into the language the aligned_new head appears not to have made it into the final draft of the C++17 standard: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf.  Updating my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks. Note that P0035R4 does nor propose `<aligned_new>` header file. It only mentions this header provided by Intel and then uses this name as exemplary in a note about backward compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

It’s on cppreference, just buried a few links deep:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new

```
new(2,f) T; // calls operator new(sizeof(T), 2, f)
        // (C++17) or operator new(sizeof(T), std::align_val_t(alignof(T)), 2, f)
```

More information on it:
https://www.bfilipek.com/2017/06/cpp17-details-clarifications.html
Looks like you actually use the `alignas` keyword and it will automatically call the new `new`.

Comment: Note that in this example, `2` and `f` has nothing to do with alignment.

Comment: For over-aligned types, _new expression_ will use the new `operator new` that reflects their alignment (just to be precise about "new `new`").

Answer (score 2):

I guess the question was how to call an overloaded `new` explicitly, whereas all answers so far advised how to do it implicitly.

My solution (floats aligned to 256-byte boundaries):

```
auto q = new (std::align_val_t(256)) float;
auto p = new (std::align_val_t(256)) float[10];
```

**Explanation**

We go to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new ("new expression') and navigate to section "Placement new":

> If placement_params are provided, they are passed to the allocation function as additional arguments

That's it!

Well, almost. Here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new we read:

> These allocation functions are called by new-expressions to allocate memory in which new object would then be initialized. They may also be called using regular function call syntax.

I was intrigued by the possibility of calling `operator new` using function call syntax. I don't think anyone does it like this. Let's try:

```
auto r = operator new (sizeof(float), std::align_val_t(256));
auto s = operator new[] (sizeof(float)*10, std::align_val_t(256)); // don't do it!!!
```

Ugly and dangerous, especially in the array-like version, as it does not have a place for the argument corresponding to the number of requested elements --  all it needs is the number of bytes to allocate, which may require taking into account some alignment overhead.

Comment: `operator new` is different from the `new` expression. The former only allocates memory (often it's a wrapper for `malloc`) whereas the latter calls `operator new` itself and then constructs the object in the memory address returned.

Comment: Good point. This would explain why people don't use "function call syntax" to construct objects.

Comment: To answer the second part of the question, `#include <new>`, then call `::operator delete[](ptr, std::align_val_t(256));`